# How to guarantee Indexeddb transactions finish for sequence of unittests?

Tags: indexeddb

Assume you're building a framework Foobar, and assume Foobar has a function .coolstuff(), which makes IndexedDB calls which calls .coolstuff2() & .coolstuff3(), and when both of these complete the transaction calls .coolstuff4().

Feel free to mix and match the above to your heart's content, through in some for loops round the various items for good measure, and various layers of asynchronicity.

Now you want to write some unit tests to test Foobar. You start by writing a test that passes some parameters into Foobar, and starts some coolstuff. At the various stages you might want to use sinon.js (or other framework) to attach hooks onto some SPECIFIC coolstuff functions to do item counts on IndexedDB or checks on the dom etc. You do this despite the difficulty of potentially counting the various times .coolstuffX() has been called in order to intercept at the right stage to do the necessary checking.

You are satisfied. The test finishes with the result you want. Now it comes time to running unittest 2.

However, .coolstuffXYZ() hasn't finished asynchronously calling whatever it needs for unittest 1.. which is going to interfere with unittest 2.

So short of relying on timers after tests (messy)... or intercepting every single function in Foobar for unittesting so that when you say your test ends it actually ends (messier, and there's no guarantee).

Is there a way for closing the database connection for the test in question and waiting for all the IndexedDB transactions to have finished... before starting up the next test? [Rhetorical because I suspect there isn't]

Or do I have to find a way to run each test in a different javascript context? Seems messy/tricky either way. Rant over.

Comment: The age old problem with designing code for testing - dependency isolation!

Comment: ... made harder when little thought to dependency isolation has been given by the underlying libraries... :-(

Comment: Hence the TDD approach of tests first...

Comment: The tests were written first. I only found out they were failing, after I'd worked out the specific problem the test was solving, and noticed that it was succeeding sometimes and failing others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a library build on top of the indexeddb. The core functionality of this framework is mostly covered by unit test. If you want to take a look how I did it, go to http://users.telenet.be/kristofdegrave/test/. I used QUnit as testing library.

The thing I do is start the next test when the first one is finished. For each test, I clean up the previous situation and start with a fresh database situation. I do this by deleting the database before I run the test, and create a new database with an initial situation for the test. This way tests can run independent and
not affect each other.

Comment: But how do you know if there aren't any transactions lying around waiting to finish before the new test starts? The underlying IndexedDB spec doesn't allow you to listen for this, so it's impossible for your framework sitting on top to listen for it. (My rant is a criticism of IndexedDB).

You can start the second test with a new database instance (I do too), but that doesn't guarantee that old .onsuccess() functions will fire after your new test has started, spoiling your counting /checking.

By the way, the link you sent me fails a number of tests (19, 24, 44). Thanx 4 answering though :-)

Comment: Depending on the browser several test fail, I know :). Did you take a close look at the source of my tests? Basically what I do is delete the database first. This way I am certain that I will create a fresh database. I do this before every test. Note: a database can't be deleted until all connections to it are closed. So this way you can be certain that no other transaction are waiting to be finished. Besides that, you are in controle of all connections that you make to the database. This way you always know when connections are open. I advice you to close the connection when a test has run.

Comment: Aaah!! That is good. Edit your answer to clarify that you mean delete the whole database and recreate it. I thought by cleanup you just meant a new instance.. maybe that was my fault, but I'd still appreciate the one or two lines more in the answer.. then I'll mark it as correct.

Just a note that the spec states that closing the database doesn't guarantee that transactions won't continue to finish later. I imagine deleting it would have to do it.